# Media Query for iPad and desktop (max-width)

Tags: css, ipad, media

**I want some CSS code to target both iPad and desktop with max-width: 768.**

This (I don't know why, would be glad to know) doesn't work for the iPad (only desktop):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
```

so I had to to this for the iPad:

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px)
```

However, I have the exact same code inside both media queries, and that I cannot accept.

I tried this also:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) or (device-width: 768px)
```

This one above doesn't work either - it actually works for the desktop, no matter what width, and not on iPad. Really strange.

How to target both iPad and desktop with same media query?

Comment: Now your code above doesn't show it, but I'm assuming you're adding the proper brackets after this @ media only and around your css: { }  ?? - As in @media only screen and (max-width:767px) { .example{width:100px;} }

Comment: It seems to me that the only solution is to use all that code as default CSS instead, and put all the CSS that 'opposes' to it inside a media query with (min-width: 769px) to target the desktop. I haven't thought of that before because I've been considering the desktop wide screen to be the default layout.. what do you people think?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a comma to include two different rules inside the @media query. This would avoid redundant CSS for both devices when the rules are the same:

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px),
       only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
/* CSS */
}
```

The following codes are specifically for iPad (portrait and landscape):

```
/* iPad Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
/* CSS */
}

/* iPad Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
/* CSS */
}
```

Hope this helps you! Let me know if you have questions or need clarification on this.

Answer (score 8):

I have used this. work for me in all device.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1199px){

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px){

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px){

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 479px){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this in your HTML then your media queries will work for both.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```